# retrofit2 upload image to server

Tags: android, retrofit2

I can't upload image to server it send multiple request to server and server is damp

this is my code

```
 @Multipart
 @POST("userImage")
 Call<ResponseBody> sendUserFeedback(@Header("SessionID") String authorization, @Part MultipartBody.Part file, @Part("uploadfile") RequestBody name);
}

selectedImageURI = data.getData();

            File file = new File(selectedImageURI.getPath());
            RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
            fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("uploadfile", file.getName(), requestBody);
            filename = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), file.getName());

private void executeSendFeedbackFormSendUserImage(String sessionID, MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload, RequestBody description){

    UploadImage userClient = retrofit1.create(UploadImage.class);

    Call<ResponseBody> call = userClient.sendUserFeedback(sessionID, fileToUpload, description);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Toast.makeText(AdminEditActivity.this,"success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (response.body() != null){

                response.code();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(AdminEditActivity.this,"error:",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

How to fix it???

Comment: Your question is not clear. Which server are you using? What's the Android OS version in which you're testing the app? And inside `onFailure()` method do not use Toast, use `Log.e("TAG", "Error ", t);` instead to log error message. After getting error logs, [edit] the question and post it along with the details I've asked in the beginning of my comment.

Comment: I get this messaage onFailure method

Comment: What's the **ERROR MESSAGE**? Please [edit] the question and post relevant information here. Did you read my previous comment clearly? Log error message using `Log.e("TAG", "Error ", t);` in `onFailure()` method.

Comment: Error 
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/image:599 (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
Tis is my error message

Comment: this error show when i add HttpLoggingInterceptor

Comment: but when I didn't add this metod it sending to server multipl requests and crash the server

Comment: Not sure whether it's causing from Android or server. Did you debug the code? Android and Server both? If you're using Android version Marshmallow or above, you need to ask runtime permission for storage access.